# How to switch between "ON" & "OFF" modes for printing line numbers in a modular document, using lineno package?

Tags: conditionals, thesis, line-numbering

**Background:** I am using the [modular document approach](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Modular_Documents) for writing my thesis. Since, the work is still in progress, I am also printing line numbers wherever needed, using the `\linenumbers` & `\nolinenumbers` commands from `lineno` package. Naturally, I have these two commands spread all over the sub-level documents for various chapters. When the work is ready to be printed, I would like to switch-off the line number printing; which means I have to remove/ comment out all the `lineno` -related commands, `\usepackage{}` setup, modified macros (if any), etc. from the main as well as all sub-level `*.tex` documents (if any).

Normally, I introduce the `lineno` package along with its re-defined macros using a `\input{file}` call. So, switching these off isn't a big problem! All I have to do is either remove or comment out this call.

However, switching off the `\linenumbers` & `\nolinenumbers` commands spread throughout all these documents is going to be time consuming.

**Problem:** So, I'd like simplify this task by re-defining `\linenumbers` & `\nolinenumbers` commands **OR** by defining corresponding new commands **OR** adding some sort of conditional sequence to the preamble **OR** a combination thereof, so that it allows me to simply switch between `\newcommand{wip}{...ON!...{\linenumbers}}` & `\newcommand{wif}{...OFF!...{\linenumbers}}`, or some other similar arrangement for both these commands. However, I can't figure out how to do it! I would like some help in this matter.

*Following is the minimal working example (MWE) and its output (For simplicity sake, I am providing MWE of a non-modular document).*

*Many thanks in advance!*

**MWE:**

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[top=1in,bottom=1.5in,left=1.5in,right=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage[babel=true]{microtype}
\usepackage{lipsum} % For sample text
\usepackage{xcolor}
%\usepackage[dvipsnames,svgnames,x11names,table]{xcolor}
%{                              %%% -- begin group!
\usepackage[left]{lineno}
\setlength\linenumbersep{12pt}
\renewcommand\linenumberfont{\normalfont\tiny\sffamily\color{lightgray}}
\modulolinenumbers[2]
%}                              %%% -- end group!
%\input{ifelsedraft}    % Actually, for the above group a \input{file} call is used!
                        % Makes commenting-out "lineno" easy!
\setlength{\parindent}{20pt}
\setlength{\parskip}{\baselineskip}

\linenumbers                % print line numbers!

\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-2]
\vspace*{20pt}
\nolinenumbers              % DO NOT print line numbers!
\lipsum[3-4]
\vspace*{20pt}
\linenumbers                % Print line numbers!
\lipsum[5-6]
\vspace*{20pt}
\nolinenumbers              % DO NOT print line numbers!
\lipsum[7-8]
\vspace*{20pt}
\linenumbers                % Print line numbers!
\lipsum[9-10]
\end{document}
```

**Output:**

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Adding `\let\linenumbers\nolinenumbers\nolinenumbers` as the last line of the preamble disables `\linenumbers` (by pointing it instead to `\nolinenumbers`) and then sets the default mode to `\nolinenumbers`.  This will allow one to retain all the invocations of `\linenumbers` in all the (sub-)documents...but they will just be ignored.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[top=1in,bottom=1.5in,left=1.5in,right=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage[babel=true]{microtype}
\usepackage{lipsum} % For sample text
\usepackage{xcolor}
%\usepackage[dvipsnames,svgnames,x11names,table]{xcolor}
%{                              %%% -- begin group!
\usepackage[left]{lineno}
\setlength\linenumbersep{12pt}
\renewcommand\linenumberfont{\normalfont\tiny\sffamily\color{lightgray}}
\modulolinenumbers[2]
%}                              %%% -- end group!
%\input{ifelsedraft}    % Actually, for the above group a \input{file} call is used!
                        % Makes commenting-out "lineno" easy!
\setlength{\parindent}{20pt}
\setlength{\parskip}{\baselineskip}

\linenumbers                % print line numbers!

\pagestyle{empty}
\let\linenumbers\nolinenumbers\nolinenumbers
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-2]
\vspace*{20pt}
\nolinenumbers              % DO NOT print line numbers!
\lipsum[3-4]
\vspace*{20pt}
\linenumbers                % Print line numbers!
\lipsum[5-6]
\vspace*{20pt}
\nolinenumbers              % DO NOT print line numbers!
\lipsum[7-8]
\vspace*{20pt}
\linenumbers                % Print line numbers!
\lipsum[9-10]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for such a wonderfully simple solution! I never thought it would be that straightforward! Now, I do feel like a fool for posting such an elaborate question! :-|

Comment: @Amar I am happy to help.  Best wishes and welcome to the site.